# Can anyone tell me title or author of following story?

Tags: story-identification, aliens, nanotechnology

Can anyone tell me the title.  Starts with hikers finding a cinder cone peak where none had existed previously in Death Valley.  Aliens had landed nano machines which had spread and started to manufacture H-Bombs and plant them on the seabed along plate boundaries.

Later an anti matter mass is impacted with earth and makes its way towards Earths core.  A signal has been detected from the aliens but no one can decode it until someone realizes its a countdown sequence.  Meanwhile good alien nanobots are working to take over the powerful people of the world in order to facilitate construction and evacuation of rescue arks to save enough humans mostly children to ensure racial survival.

Earth is destroyed by explosions as the Arks depart Earth.  Children are forced to watch earth destroyed to make sure they are pissed enough to seek revenge when possible.  Good solid science in this one.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/193422/science-fiction-book-regarding-earths-destruction-by-aliens (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 8):

Sounds like [Forge of God](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Forge_of_God) (1987) by Greg Bear. (I've been meaning to find a copy to reread it. I particularly recall the appearance of a duplicate of Ayers Rock (Uluru).)

One alien faction is determined to destroy civilizations, the other to preserve representatives. (A plotline that also shows up in the movie Independence Day: Resurgence.) The cataclysm at the end is particularly well-described.

There is a sequel: Anvil of Stars (no spoilers).